# Facial Motion Capture Help

Tags: constraints, tracking, motion-capture

I'm trying to apply facial tracking markers to a 3D model and I've run into a bit of a snag.. While setting the constraint depths of the trackers to a face mesh, the trackers stay locked in below the model. I notice that the Location and Rotation settings in the Transform window are now yellow, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with why they're locked. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @RayMairlot, I ended up finding a solution. I was having trouble constraining the empties to the 3D model because I some how animated them which prevented me from being able to change their position.

Comment: If you have a solution you should post it below in the answer box below. And, as I said, you should [edit] your question title so it is specific to what you are asking.